# VSCode - Display theme scope for selected text

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write a custom theme for vscode. In order to do this I need to know the theme scope that was applied to each token when vscode tokenized the source code.

For example was a particular keyword in the source tagged as `constant.numeric` or just `constant`.

Is there anyway to display this information?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ctrl+shift+p and type in "scope", the fuzzy search should find you the command "Developer: Inspect TM Scopes"

Comment: This at last answers a question I was looking to solve: how to change the color of tag chevrons in html, such as the chevrons in <p></p>. and more generally how to change the color of an item that is not defined in the theme you are based on.

Comment: The command is nowadays called "Developer: Inspect Tokens and Scopes".